# awk 2 files find and update min/max values

Tags: awk, max, min

This is the second part of my [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731235/awk-compare-2-files-find-min-max-and-store-it?rq=1).

File_1 is polled every second, the $2 is changing all the time:

```
0             0.00
1             0.00
2             0.00
3             0.00
4             0.00
5             0.00
6             0.00
7             0.00
8           -40.00
9           -20.00
10          -10.00
11           10.00
12           30.00
13           20.00
14           10.00
15           20.00
16           10.00
17          -10.00
18          -10.00
19          -10.00
20          -10.00
21          -10.00
22           10.00
23            0.00
```

File_2 is where I want to store min ($1) and max ($2) values and update them. The original File_2 is empty:

```
0       0.0000      0.0000
1       0.0000      0.0000
2       0.0000      0.0000
3       0.0000      0.0000
4       0.0000      0.0000
5       0.0000      0.0000
6       0.0000      0.0000
7       0.0000      0.0000
8       0.0000      0.0000
9       0.0000      0.0000
10      0.0000      0.0000
11      0.0000      0.0000
12      0.0000      0.0000
13      0.0000      0.0000
14      0.0000      0.0000
15      0.0000      0.0000
16      0.0000      0.0000
17      0.0000      0.0000
18      0.0000      0.0000
19      0.0000      0.0000
20      0.0000      0.0000
21      0.0000      0.0000
22      0.0000      0.0000
23      0.0000      0.0000
```

I want to store the absolute min and max values in File_2 and update them if a newly polled File_1 $1 contains higher/lower values. That means File_1 $1 has to be checked with File_2 $1 and $2 and if File_1 $1 is lower than File_2 $1 or higher than File_2 $2, then File_2 $1 or File_2 $2 has to be updated. All files are sorted.

Explanation:

This is going to be a radio frequency noise analyzer. Every line is a subchannel, where the rise or drop of the ingress RF noise is measured and read every second (stored in File_1). The goal is to get the absolute minimum and maximum values (or with other words the noise variation) during the measurement for every subchannel (every line) and store it in File_2 for further study.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it using `paste` and `AWK` combination. This is the line:

```
paste File_1 File_2 | awk '{min = $4; if ($2 < $4){min = $2;} max = $5; if ($2 > $5){max = $2;}print $1"\t"min"\t"max;}' -
```

You can redirect the output wherever you want to save it. See explanation below.

Here is the output:

```
0   0.0000  0.0000
1   0.0000  0.0000
2   0.0000  0.0000
3   0.0000  0.0000
4   0.0000  0.0000
5   0.0000  0.0000
6   0.0000  0.0000
7   0.0000  0.0000
8   -40.00  0.0000
9   -20.00  0.0000
10  -10.00  0.0000
11  0.0000  10.00
12  0.0000  30.00
13  0.0000  20.00
14  0.0000  10.00
15  0.0000  20.00
16  0.0000  10.00
17  -10.00  0.0000
18  -10.00  0.0000
19  -10.00  0.0000
20  -10.00  0.0000
21  -10.00  0.0000
22  0.0000  10.00
23  0.0000  0.0000
```

Explanation:

First of all, using `paste` I get "both files in one", then I just check for min and max values (if statements in `AWK` code) and I print the final result for each line.

PS: Try `paste File_1 File_2` if you do not know how it works.

Comment: Thanks! Will test tomorrow with RF simulator and come back hopefully with thumbs up :)

Comment: Jajaja I hope so. If you have any problem, just let me know ;-)

Comment: There is one tiny problem: on the target platform there is no paste utility. There is awk and sed, but paste is missing from busybox. It is possible to replace the "paste" command somehow?

Comment: This is a MIPS32 based embedded system with busybox 1.9.1. Awk and Sed are in-built but I can compile other busybox parts if you need any of them for the solution. Anyway, it would be nice to solve this with awk too. Thanks for you effort!

Comment: I found an awk one liner to replace paste:
awk 'FNR == NR { first[FNR]=$0; next } { print $0 "\t", (FNR in first) ? first[FNR] : "" }' File_1 File_2 > output

Comment: It seems some adjustment is needed. I will report back with the results.

Comment: It seems only the input file order was the problem. So the following script can replace the paste utility:

awk 'FNR == NR { first[FNR]=$0; next } { print $0 "\t", (FNR in first) ? first[FNR] : "" }' File_2 File_1 > output

arotaku: your solution also works, thank you for that. It seems the whole concept is working fine, some adjustment with the plotting/graphing scripts will do the trick.